# problem with silhouette score with affinity propagation

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

I try to run this code but i have an error : ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive). Furthermore, it is said that : Affinity propagation did not converge, this model will not have any cluster centers. What is the solution for these 2 problems

````
preferences = range(-15000,-5000,50) # arbitraty chosen range
af_sil_score = [] # silouette scores

for p in preferences:
    AF = AffinityPropagation(preference=p, max_iter=200).fit(X)
    no_of_clusters.append((len(np.unique(AF.labels_))))
    af_sil_score.append(silhouette_score(X, AF.labels_))
    
af_results = pd.DataFrame([preferences, no_of_clusters, af_sil_score], index=['preference','clusters', 'sil_score']).T
af_results.sort_values(by='sil_score', ascending=False).head() # display only 5 best scores```
````

Answer (score 0):

For some of your values of preference , it is not suitable for your dataset, and will not converge (giving you the convergence error). When the algorithm fails, it does not return labels and it doesn't make sense to apply `silhouette_score` (your second error).

You can check this [page](http://genes.toronto.edu/affinitypropagation/faq.html) or other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187354/affinity-propagation-preferences-initialization) to see how to set the preference value. Or you can simply try a range of values, and simply return -1 when the number of clusters is below 2.

```
Using an example :

from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import pandas as pd

X, labels_true = make_blobs( n_samples=250, random_state=0, n_features =5, centers = 3 )

preferences = range(-1000,-100,100) 
af_sil_score = [] # silouette scores
no_of_clusters = []

for p in preferences:

    AF = AffinityPropagation(preference=p, max_iter=200).fit(X)
    no_of_clusters.append(len(AF.cluster_centers_))
    if len(AF.cluster_centers_) > 1:
        af_sil_score.append(silhouette_score(X, AF.labels_))
    else :
        af_sil_score.append(-1)
```

Results look like this, you can see it starts to work around -500 in the example dataset above :

```
pd.DataFrame({'preferences':preferences,'no_of_clusters':no_of_clusters,'sil':af_sil_score})

   preferences  no_of_clusters       sil
0        -1000               0 -1.000000
1         -900               0 -1.000000
2         -800               0 -1.000000
3         -700               0 -1.000000
4         -600               0 -1.000000
5         -500               3  0.716733
6         -400               3  0.716733
7         -300               3  0.716733
8         -200               3  0.716733
```